# How to get Hadoop's Generic Options value

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

As you know, Hadoop support the [Generic Options](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options). For example you can use "-files" to specify files to be copied to the map reduce cluster.

But how to get the value of Generic Options? For example, I have a command that is :

> hadoop jar job.jar JobClass -files
>   /home/MapReduce/testFile.json input output

As you see, I'm using the generic option "-files", and the value of this option is "/home/MapReduce/testFile.json", so how can I get this value?

I tried [GenericOptionsParser](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html) class like this:

```
String option = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getCommandLine().getOptionValue("files");
```

But the result was NULL. I also changed the parameter of .getOptionValue() to "-files", got NULL as well.

And I also tried the code like this:

```
String[] toolArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
```

But the above code only get all the remaining command options other than the generic options, that is the contrary of my expectation.

Comment: When you say the result is incorrect, what do you get?

Comment: @LokeshA.R. The result was NULL. I updated my question. Thanks!